# why do some use ν=n instead of ν=n-1 in the t distribution

Tags: t-distribution, marginal-distribution

I have always accepted that ν=n-1, but then I come across multiple authors showing a derivation of the t distribution by marginalizing out the variance from the normal-inverse-gamma distribution, or by marginalizing out the inverse variance (precision) from the normal-gamma distribution.

The results of deriving the t distribution from the normal-inverse-gamma distribution require the use of ν=n and not ν=n-1.

For example in the book "Bayesian Data Analysis: Third edition" on page 69, it derives $p(μ|μ_0,σ_0)=t(μ|μ=μ_n,σ=σ_n^2/κ_n,ν=ν_n)$ where
$$ μ_n={κ_0\over κ_0+n}μ_0+{n\over κ_0+n}\bar y $$
$$ κ_n=κ_0+n $$
$$ ν_n=ν_0+ν $$
$$ ν_nσ_n=ν_0σ_0^2+(n-1)s^2+{κ_0n\over κ_0+n}(\bar y-μ_0)^2 $$

Since the least informative prior has $κ_0=ν_0=0$ therefore $ν_n=ν_0+n=n$.  For example when using a normal gamma distribution to derive the t distribution, the prior on the precision is $Γ(α=ν_0/2,β=ν_0σ_0^2/2)$ [[1]](https://web.ics.purdue.edu/%7Eibilion/www.zabaras.com/Courses/BayesianComputing/StudentT.pdf) where clearly the least informative prior is obtained in the limit as $ν_0$ approaches 0.  Yet on page 66 ν=n-1 is derived, and seems to be correct.

Even if $ν_n=ν_0+n$ is correct there is no way to obtain $ν=n-1$ without $ν_0=-1$, which I can not make sense of, with a gamma or inverse gamma distribution.

I clearly must have some fundamental misunderstanding. What is it?

I thought that perhaps $σ_n$ would cancel out the different value of ν, but no, instead I get two different results depending on which derivation of the t distribution I use.

How do I get the same results from the two different derivations of the t distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is in the prior distributions.

- The book starts with

  $$p(\mu,\sigma) \propto \sigma^{-2} \phantom{\cdot \sigma^{-1} e^{- \frac{(\mu-\mu_0)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}$$

  From which the t-distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom is derived as the marginal posterior distribution.
- The second derivation uses*

  $$p(\mu,\sigma) \propto \sigma^{-2} \cdot \sigma^{-1} e^{- \frac{(\mu-\mu_0)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

  From which the t-distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom is derived as the marginal posterior distribution.

So the difference is in the prior distribution. The former is uniform in $\mu$. With the latter this is not the case and you get a multiplication of this $\sigma^{-2}$ with a term for the distribution of $\mu$ conditional on $\sigma$. This changes the power from $\sigma^{-2}$ into $\sigma^{-3}$ and that changes the end result when you integrate out the $\sigma$.

---

<sup>*I have simplified it with $\nu_0 =0$ such that the difference between the two situations is more clear. But, the second case is more general and with $\nu_0\neq 0$ the equation is more complex. $$p(\mu,\sigma) \propto \sigma^{-2} \sigma^{-\nu_0} \exp \left( - \frac{1}{2\sigma^2} [\nu_0 \sigma_0^2 + \kappa_0(\mu_0-\mu)^2] \right)$$ But this complexity is not needed to see the difference why you get $n-1$ versus $n$.</sup>

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying out here? The $\nu_0$ is the degrees of freedom of the inverse chi-squared distribution that is the prior for $\sigma$. This value should be a positive integer.

Comment: alright, maybe this time I will say things sufficiently and correctly: $p(σ^2;ν_0,σ_0^2)\propto (σ^2)^{-(1+ν_0/2)}e^{\frac{-ν_0σ_0^2}{2σ^2}}$ and $p(μ|σ^2)\propto (σ^2)^{-1/2}e^{\frac{-κ_0}{2σ^2}(μ-μ_0)^2}$ so when $ν_0=-1$ and $ν_0σ_0^2=κ_0=0$ then $p(μ,σ^2)\propto p(σ^2;ν_0,σ_0^2)\cdot p(μ|σ^2)\propto \sigma^-1\cdot\sigma^-1$, because $(σ^2)^{-(1+ν_0/2)}=σ^{-1}$ when $ν_0=-1$ and $ν_0σ_0^2=κ_0=0$.

Comment: what I am trying to do is bridge the gap between the two "different" priors, and get a point of view that makes sense, even if it requires negative parameters for the inverse gamma distribution, which ordinarily would be undefined or result in complex values, but when ν_0=-1 and $ν_0σ^2_0=0$, and use $IG(\alpha=\nu_0/2,\beta=\nu_0\sigma_0^2/2)=IG(\alpha=-1/2,\beta=0)$ everything does end up working.

Comment: for reference $I_{\chi^2}(ν_0,σ^2_0)=IG(\alpha=\nu_0/2,\beta=\nu_0\sigma_0^2/2)$

Comment: sigh... now I see $σ^-1σ^-1$ ... I ment $σ^{-1}σ^{-1}$.  (In the fight against sleep, I always lose, every time)

Comment: ν_0 should be positive...  It is like saying if you have n samples then you have n-1 degrees of freedom, so if you have one sample then you have zero degrees of freedom and if you have no data then you have -1 degrees of freedom, which both sound like non-sense, but the math works out, and eliminates the difference between the two priors.